# Simplest way to model real world entities into a database

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

Hi database experts,
I have a question that is more focused on theory, but I would also be interested in some pratical advices, if possible.

I need to create a system where common people (not IT specialists) can model real world entities that will be saved inside a relational database with an automatic translation. For example, one could model a bookstore, saying that there are many books, that each book has one or more authors, and so on.

I feel ER is difficult to understand for common people, especially relationships. I need a simpler method to express objects and their associations, but I don't know where to start.

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 0):

since theory involve in providing the [Simplest way to model real world entities into a database] i would say enumerate all real world entities and represent them in nice big boxes so users can select the related entities to his/her project domain. then the system will produce fully functional model [still in theory]. i couldn't think of simpler one!

Comment: Yes, I thought of this solution. But it would be difficult to model every possible attribute for every possibile entity.